# Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper error on TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, teamcity

Although my solution is building on my local machine, it throws this error on TeamCity when I use "Visual Studio (sln)" as the runner for the build step:

[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPlatformSDKDisplayName($(TargetPlatformIdentifier), $(TargetPlatformVersion))". Method 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper.GetPlatformSDKDisplayName' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).

Any idea what I'm missing on the TeamCity side ?
Do I need to change MSBuild runner ?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Just started getting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this is trying to find the path to the SDK from the Registry and it's unable to find it.

Try installing Visual Studio Community Edition on the build server and this should fix your issue

[Visual Studio Community Edition Download Page](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)

[Visual Studio 2013 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40758)

Comment: What SDK you talking about ?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you trying to use in the Build Runner?

Comment: Then you need the 2013 SDK to build 2013 solutions. You can either have just the SDK (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40758) or the Community Edition will install that too